# Maintaining a .NET OdbcConnection object over a long time

Tags: c#, .net, orm, odbc

I have a very small Data abstraction class inside a very long running service.  It is a static class and called statelessly as a cross-class utility (like just `DataTable someResults = Data.SelectFooFromBar()`) -- I don't want to be instancing this in several discrete and unrelated classes.  The service does `Data.Initialize(connectionString)` as it comes up.  The `Initialize` looks like:

```
private static string connectionString;
private static OdbcConnection connection;

public static void Initialize(string mySqlConnectionString)
{
   /*mySqlConnectionString would look something like this:
     "Provider=MSDASQL;
      Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};
      UID=some_db_user;
      PWD=some_db_pass;
      Server=db-host;
      Port=3306;
      Database=some_db;
      Protocol=TCP;
      Compress=false;
      Pooling=true;
      Min Pool Size=0;
      Max Pool Size=100;
      Connection Lifetime=0;
      OPTION=16386;"*/

   //Ensure only one connection exists to prevent leaks, and also
   // only modify the connection if the connection string has changed:
   if (connection == null || connectionString != mySqlConnectionString)
   {
      connectionString = mySqlConnectionString;
      connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
   }
}
```

And here is a method used by the public facing method that actually sanitizes and executes the query:

```
private static DataTable Select(string query)
{
   try
   {
      query = Sanitize(query);

      connection.Open();
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(query, connection);
      da.Fill(dt);
      connection.Close();

      return dt;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      connection.Close();
      ExceptionHandler(ex, query);
      return null;
   }
}
```

And finally an actual public facing data method:

```
public static DataTable SelectFooFromBar()
{
   return Select("SELECT foo FROM bar");
}
```

My question is what is the best way to ensure my `connection` object is always good?

- Are there events that can be handled or something when the connection goes bad?
- Also is it good or bad to be opening/closing the `connection` object every time a query is run?
- Should I just have multiple `catches` so I can, say, do a `connection.Close()` and move on when it was a query level error, but to a `connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString)` when my exception indicates to me I am disconnected (not sure which exception this is)

  It kind of seems bad to leave it Open all the time, but I wanted to get a second opinion.

Comment: Use the `using` statement.

Comment: Making a static connection is a very bad idea.

Comment: @SLaks I do use parameters.  I simply put the Sanitize call in to simplify the snippets.  Also why is a static connection bad?  Thanks.

Comment: If you ever need to use it from multiple threads, or re-entrantly inside a DataReader, things will break.

Comment: @SLaks Sorry if it's obvious, but can you go a bit deeper on the specific cross thread issues?

Comment: ADO.Net is not thread-safe.  If you use a single connection on multiple threads, everything will go horribly wrong.

Comment: @SLaks Gotcha.  I previously had the Data class just create a new OdbcConnection for each operation so it could fail atomically and be thread safe, but it was generating lots of TIME_WAIT connections.  So I think I just need to revert and sharply lower my Max Pool size to minimize these TIME_WAIT connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be opening up a new connection for every single operation, rather than opening up one connection and reusing it.

Behind the scenes the actual DB adapter will have a connection pool.  A number of connections that it keeps open and assigns when a new connection is requested.  Normally creating a new connection is expensive, but due to connection pooling this expense is simply not felt when creating a lot of connections for short periods of use.

(Of course, you'd want to make sure connection pooling is enabled in your DB configuration, but based on what you showed, it clearly already is.)

If your connection fails to connect it will throw an exception.  Let that exception bubble up to somewhere that can appropriately deal with the situation.  This is almost certainly not your DAL, but rather up into your business logic where you can, in some way, inform the user of the error and determine what should be done about it.

Comment: It's funny you mention that because that is exactly the way it used to be.  The problem is that the Data class is constantly processing lots of calls, and so it generates thousands of TIME_WAIT connections, which in turn occupy lots of resources on other pieces of network infrastructure that have to maintain the connection states.  So I decided to try just having a single connection to eliminate this problem.

Comment: @kmarks2 Lower the max number of connections in your pool to a more manageable number, if you don't have the resources to support that many.

Comment: I think I will revert to the way I had it before (new connection for each operation) and will substantially lower the thread pool size.  The advice is much appreciated, Servy.

Comment: Actually my max pool size is 100 and I'm see 1500+ TIME_WAIT connections.  Have their been any known issues with Odbc Connector pooling?

Comment: @kmarks2 same problem with max pool size being 2 and seeing around 20 user sessions (i.e. connections?) :(

Answer (score 1):

You should not leave it open all the time. You will have to write even more code to monitor the state of the connection and handle timeout situations, network connectivity issues, etc. for a long running open connection.

You will notice that most people wrap connection in Using. There isn't much cost in establishing your connection as needed.

Comment: So you are saying to create a new connection, open it, operate on it and close it each time a query needs to be processed?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a connection pool, create a function GetConnection that returns an open connection.  Inside this function, test if the global connection object is null or closed.  If so, re-open it.  It doesn't matter if the connection closes, all that matters is that it's open when you need it.

Comment: I am using a connection pool.  Min=0, Max=100.

Comment: You still then need to deal with multiple threads calling any of the DAL's methods concurrently.

Comment: In that case the pool is doing most of the work for you.  You don't really close a connection when releasing it, it goes back to the pool for reuse.